# Get and verify file names in a directory - Java

Tags: java

There are three files in the directory and I need to verify if there all from the same set. This is based on the 3 files using the same naming structure. One file is slightly different. Here is an example:
      2014_UMW.xxx
      2014_UMW.yyy
      2014_UMW_web.zzz

2014_UMW is just one example. It has to work with all data sets.

I need to check that the three files match and have the same data set. I have written code to get the file names from the directory, drop the file extension and store the file name as a string. Now i need to compare the file names to see if they are equal. If they are equal the method should return true. I am having trouble figuring out how to deal with the file name that contains the _web. What is the best way to handle this issue.

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.*;

public class Verify_FileName {

```
private static void getAllFiles(File curDir) throws IOException{

    File[] filesList = curDir.listFiles();
    for(File f: filesList){
        if(f.isFile()){
            String File = FileUtils.readFileToString(f);
            FilenameUtils.removeExtension(File);

            String [] FileWithoutExtension = new String [filesList.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < filesList.length; i++){
                FileWithoutExtension[i] = File;                 
            }

        }

    }

}

public static boolean compareFileNames(String [] f){



}
```

}

Comment: if they all have 2014_UMW, then maybe you should just use string.contains("2014_UMW") and that should work on all the files even the one with _web

Comment: Use a regular expression or `String#startsWith` and `String#endsWith`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how specific you want to make the comparison, you could split on "_" and verify the resulting string arrays are equivalent:

```
String[] firstFileName = "2014_UMW_web".split("_");
String[] secondFileName = "2014_UMW".split("_");
if (firstFileName.length != secondFileName.length) {
  return false;
}
for (int i = 0;i < firstFileName.length;i++) {
  if (!secondFileName[i].equals(firstFileName[i]) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
```

Comment: 2014_UMW is just one example, it has to work for file names associated with other data set.